# Why is $\sec^2 (\tan^{-1} (\frac{x}{2})) = 1 + \tan^2 (\tan^{-1} (\frac{x}{2}))$ and not $(1 + \tan^2 )(\tan^{-1} (\frac{x}{2}))$?

Tags: trigonometry

> Why is $\sec^2 (\tan^{-1} (\frac{x}{2})) = 1 + \tan^2 (\tan^{-1} (\frac{x}{2}))$ and not $(1 + \tan^2 )(\tan^{-1} (\frac{x}{2}))$?

If you replace $\sec^2$ with $\tan^2 + 1$, it should be $(1 + \tan^2 )(\tan^{-1} (\frac{x}{2}))$, right?

However, it seems that it is not multiplication here : $\sec^2 (\tan^{-1} (\frac{x}{2}))$, when the $1$ becomes independent of the $\tan^2$ somehow.

Could someone explain why?

Comment: *"it seems that it is not multiplication here"* ... Correct. Applying a function (in particular, a trig function) is *not* multiplication. "$f(x)$" is not "$f\;\text{times}\;x$", it's "$f\;\text{evaluated at}\; x$"; likewise, "$\sec^2x$" is not "$\sec^2\;\text{times}\; x$", it's "$\sec^2\;\text{evaluated at}\;x$". Also, while it's convenient shorthand to say "sec-squared is tan-squared plus $1$", it's important to keep in mind that what's *meant* is (deep breath) "the square of secant-evaluated-at-$x$, is equal to the square of tangent-evaluated-at-$x$, plus $1$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct statement is $\sec^2(y)=1+\tan^2(y)$.

Now let $y=\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac x2\right)$.

I hope this helps you see why.

Answer (score 1):

The identity
$$\sec^2\theta\equiv1+\tan^2\theta$$
holds for *all values of $\theta$*, not just some values- that's why it's an identity, as opposed to an equation. Replacing $\theta$ by $\tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{2})$ yields the correct identity:
$$\sec^2(\tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{2}))\equiv1+\tan^2(\tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{2}))\equiv1+\left(\tan(\tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{2}))\right)^2\equiv1+\frac{x^2}{4}$$
**Edit**
Thinking that $\sec^2\theta$ means $\sec^2\times\theta$ is meaningless- $\sec^2$ or indeed any other trigonometrical function has no meaning *unless* it has an argument, ie the value the that is an input into the trigonometical function (in your case $\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{2}$).